# How to get different button click? such as playButton1, playButton2, playButton3,

Tags: android

I am making an application for Android and I have some buttons to play and pause and stop. How to get different button click? such as playButton1, playButton2, playButton3, etc .., or with different buttons and music, code below.. (I'M Newbie)

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.cdp.keroncong;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MediaPlayer Song;
    int pause;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
    }
    public void play(View view){
        if(Song == null){
            Song = MediaPlayer.create(this , R.raw.playButton1/music1);
            Song.start();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Song Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
        }

        else if(!Song.isPlaying()){
            Song.seekTo(pause);
            Song.start();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Song Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     
       }
    }
    public void pause(View view){
        if(Song!= null){
            Song.pause();
            pause = Song.getCurrentPosition();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Song Pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    public void stop(View view){

        Song.stop();
        Song = null;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Song Stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Thank's before

Comment: Do you want control the song state with different buttons? I mean a button to play, button to stop. Is that your question?

Comment: Please show your xml file

Comment: I want to add new button to play, button to pause and stop with different song, i mean button1 = play music 1, button2 = play music2 etc ..

Comment: Sorry I'm newbie learn android ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put your all methods outside of your onCreate()
and set in your xml
 `android:onClick="play"`
`android:onClick="pause"`
`android:onClick="stop"`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); }

}

  public void play(View view){
        if(Song == null){
            Song = MediaPlayer.create(this , R.raw.playButton1/music1);
            Song.start();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Song Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    }

        else if(!Song.isPlaying()){
            Song.seekTo(pause);
            Song.start();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Song Play", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();     }
    }
    public void pause(View view){
        if(Song!= null){
            Song.pause();
            pause = Song.getCurrentPosition();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Song Pause", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    public void stop(View view){

        Song.stop();
        Song = null;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Song Stop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```